# call multiple functions in on single click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to call three functions on a JSX click event the thing is there three functions are `saveData` `clearData` and `loadData` inside a `multiFunc` and what the first 2 functions work as expected I can see that by printing out their content in the console but the 3rd functions does not work until a click again to call the `multiFunc` what i want to do is to click the JSX event and execute each function in one single click. this is my code so far

```
  const [savedImageData, setSavedImageData] = useState(null);

  const saveData = async () => {
    if (canvasRef.current) {
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;
      const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  
      setSavedImageData(dataURL);
      setStore(prevStore => [...prevStore, dataURL]);
      console.log(dataURL);
      console.log('data saved');
    }
  };

 const clearData = () => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    console.log('data cleared ')
    return true 
  };

  const loadData = () => {
    if (savedImageData) {
      setImageUrl(savedImageData);
      console.log(savedImageData)
      setIsRetrieveData(true);
      setIsDrawing(false); // Reset the drawing state
      console.log('data loaded ')
     
    }
  };
```

and these is the function I want to call in

```
const multiFunc = () => {
      saveD();
      clearData();
      loadData();
  };

///JSX
      <button onClick={multiFunc}>next</button>
```

I want to make it work one by one on one click I already tried to async/await and promise on the `multiFunc` but did not work I still have to lick twice for the `loadData` to work, it seems to me that I issue is in the logic inside of the `loadData` function but what do you suggest?

Comment: Updated state values are not available until the next render cycle so `if (savedImageData)` will always be evaluating the state value before the value has been set by `saveData` (even if it weren't since `saveData` is async and you're not awaiting it `loadData` would be run before `saveData` completed.) Generally side effects should be accounted for in the handlers themselves, but in this case it looks like you want a `useEffect` dependent on `savedImageData`

Comment: see the docs: [React: You Might Not Need an Effect](https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect) and [React: Synchronizing with Effects](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects)

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `load` function inside a `useEffect`. Your code isn’t working as expected because when `load` is being called `savedImageData` is `null`. The `useEffect` will ensure `load` is only called when `savedImageData` is not `null`

```
export default function App() {
  const [savedImageData, setSavedImageData] = React.useState(null);

  const saveData = async () => {
    if (!canvasRef.current) return;
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

    setSavedImageData(dataURL);
    setStore((prevStore) => [...prevStore, dataURL]);
  };

  const clearData = () => {
    const canvas = canvasRef.current;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    console.log('data cleared ');
    return true;
  };

  const loadData = (imageData) => {
    if (!imageData) return;
    setImageUrl(imageData);
    setIsRetrieveData(true);
    setIsDrawing(false); // Reset the drawing state
  };

  const handleClick = async () => {
    await saveData();
    clearData();
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    loadData(savedImageData);
  }, [savedImageData]);

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>next</button>;
}
```